# DDNS records read from secondary DNS

Tags: dhcp, bind, ddns

I use BIND9 with DHCPD(Centos 7) and configured DDNS. It works well on this server. Question is how I can read DDNS records on secondary DNS(Bind9) from this primary DNS ?  I configured slave zone on secundary DNS but I can read only static records. Is it possible to replicate DDNS records too ?

Comment: Are you sure the records are actually in the same zone? In my experience, records are just _dynamically added_ (but not fully dynamic), so they still get stored statically and are visible in AXFR.

Comment: I use the same zone, but Bind created jnl files for DDNS.I checked by nslookup and it works on this server. Not sure if it is possible to replicate DDNS records using AXFR? Maybe I'm wrong. Maybe forwarding questions from a another DNS server is the right way?